# Attempt to index global 'websocket'

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I'm pretty new to the ESP8266. I'm trying to add the WebSockets to the Lua code, but everytime I try to use the WebSocket looking at the [documentation](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/websocket/), the device throws error as attempt to index global `websocket` (a `nil` value). I'm not really sure if there is something to be imported, can anyone please help me with this.

```lua
function connectToSocket()
    print ("Connect to socket called, OK.")
    local ws_client = websocket.createClient()
end

wifi.setphymode(wifi.PHYMODE_N)
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.sta.config("SSID","PWD")
wifi.sta.eventMonReg(wifi.STA_IDLE, function() print("IDLE") end)
wifi.sta.eventMonReg(wifi.STA_CONNECTING, function() print("CONNECTING...") end)
wifi.sta.eventMonReg(wifi.STA_WRONGPWD, function() print("WRONG PASSWORD!!!") end)
wifi.sta.eventMonReg(wifi.STA_APNOTFOUND, function() print("NO SUCH SSID FOUND") end)
wifi.sta.eventMonReg(wifi.STA_FAIL, function() print("FAILED TO CONNECT") end)
wifi.sta.eventMonReg(wifi.STA_GOTIP, function() 
    print("GOT IP "..wifi.sta.getip()) 
    connectToSocket()
end)
wifi.sta.eventMonStart()
wifi.sta.connect()
```

Comment: How did you configure your NodeMCU firmware build? (https://nodemcu-build.com/) Did you try to put `websocket = require("websocket")` as the first line of the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three problems with the above code.

The main issue appears to be that your firmware is missing the `websocket` module. Uncomment https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/master/app/include/user_modules.h#L75 if you happen to build it manually.

Furthermore, all event handlers need to be registered before the respective events have a chance to be fired. I see you *intend* to do exactly that. However, by default [`wifi.sta.config`](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/wifi/#wifistaconfig) uses `auto connect=true` in which case the WiFi registration process starts before the event monitor is started.

Lastly, the signature for `wifi.sta.config` changed a few months ago (see docs for details). Now you'd have to say `wifi.sta.config{"SSID","PWD"}` thereby passing a Lua table.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, when I observed the message after the reboot, the websocket module is missing. Then I made another build with websockets. Thanks @Marcel